# Outlinedinput from @material-ui labelWidth giving error for react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a small form with the size 300(width) and 400 (height). I tried to import Outlinedinput from '@material-ui'. The issue is that it needs labelWidth compulsorily. I gave it like this: `<Outlinedinput  labelWidth = 200 />` but i get an error saying `Failed prop type: The prop 'labelWidth' is marked as required in 'OutlinedInput', but its value is 'undefined'`. I tried setting it with style like this : `style={{width: 700}}` and i get the same error. How do i set number to labelWidth the correct way.

`https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/`

```
import Outlinedinput from '@material-ui/core/Outlinedinput';

render(){
  return(
    <Outlinedinput style={{width: 300}} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be putting curly braces around the number value like so:

```
<OutlinedInput
    labelWidth={200}
/>
```

An example with source code of how to use this component is demonstrated on the Material-UI examples page at https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#components